# How can I replace screen with React Navigation for React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

How can I replace screen with React Navigation for React Native

Now I'm a newbie I can't understand about getStateForAction
now I have params on Screen 1 and Navigate to Screen 2 with passing params username with basic Navigate it's nested screen 1 > 2 on stack

But I need to replace screen 1 with screen 2 after screen 2 it's on active (replace like ActionConst.REPLACE on router flux) and sending params on a new way

Can someone guide me thank you.

---

---

screen 1

```
  onPress = () => {

          this.props.navigation.navigate('Sc2', {username: this.state.username});

  }
```

---

---

Screen 2

```
componentWillMount() {

const {state} = this.props.navigation;
console.log(state.params.username);

}
```

### ---------------

Router

```
export const LoginNavStack = StackNavigator({
  Sc1: {
    screen: Sc1
  },
  Sc2: {
   screen: Sc2,
 },

});
```

Answer (score 20):

Incase anyone's still figuring out how to replace screens in React Native and is using `react-navigation`, here it is:

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  StackActions.replace('Profile', {
    user: 'jane',
  })
);
```

For more information refer: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#replace

Answer (score 8):

Use this instead of navigation.replace

```
navigation.reset({
 index: 0,
 routes: [{ name: 'Profile' }],
 });
```

Comment: Important note here for navigation.reset(), it will clear out your navigation stack and replace it with new screen.

This may not be the behaviour you want when you still need to preserve some navigation history.

For example:

`Navigation stack: Home -> Profile -> Settings`

If you call reset in settings screen and pass profile, the stack will look like this

`New Navigation stack: Profile`

Problem with this is that when you want to navigate back to Home, it will close the app, since there's no previous screen in the stack

Comment: This worked for me in react-navigation 6 with `const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProp<SomeStackParamList>>()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me.

```
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native'

const Home = (nav:any) => {
    const goToLogin = () => {
        nav.navigation.replace('Login');
    }
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <Button title='Go To Login' onPress={goToLogin} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `navigation.replace`

Use

```
this.props.navigation.replace('Sc2');
```

Instead of

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Sc2', {username: this.state.username});
```

You can find more from here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-key.html

Comment: How can we use replace in Typescript? I get this ```Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'NavigationProp<Record<string, object | undefined>, string, NavigationState, {}, {}>'.ts(2339)```

Comment: How will I pass any information to the other screen when I am using navigation.replace??

Answer (score 2):

"Replace" is only available in stack navigation

replace typed:

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack'

type YourNavigatorParamList = {
  CurrentScreen: undefined
  DifferentScreen: { username: string }
}

const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<YourNavigatorParamList, 'CurrentScreen'>>()

navigation.replace('DifferentScreen', { username: 'user01' })
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#navigator-dependent-functions
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript#annotating-usenavigation